# Coefficient Significance in Regression with Arima Errors

Tags: r, regression, forecasting, arima, regression-coefficients

In the R package forecast, when you run dynamic regression (regression with arima errors), the coefficients and their standard error are output, but there is no significance test available for the coefficients. I am wondering why this is-- does variable significance in the typical sense (t-test) not hold when adding in Arima terms to the model?

An example of this would be

```
library(fpp2)
library(forecast)

auto.arima(uschange[, "Consumption"],
       xreg = uschange[, "Income"])


Series: uschange[, "Consumption"] 
Regression with ARIMA(1,0,2) errors 

Coefficients:
        ar1      ma1     ma2  intercept    xreg
      0.6922  -0.5758  0.1984     0.5990  0.2028
s.e.  0.1159   0.1301  0.0756     0.0884  0.0461

sigma^2 estimated as 0.3219:  log likelihood=-156.95
AIC=325.91   AICc=326.37   BIC=345.29
```

Answer (score 10):

The forecast package does forecasting. For that purpose, the significance of variables is irrelevant. What matters is whether a variable is useful for forecasting. The AIC is a good guide for selecting variables for forecasting, so the package minimizes the AIC. If you really want to do a significance test on a variable, just compute the t-statistics from the output.

In the example provided, the t-statistic for income is 0.2028/0.0461 = 4.4. The p-value is `2*(1-pt(0.2028/0.0461, NROW(fpp2::uschange)-5)) = 1.8e-5`

Comment: I thought that might have been the case, but it is great to hear it from the straight horses mouth. Thanks Dr. Hyndman!

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't interested in realistic(ie wide) confidence limits then this is ok, but if you want good confidence limits then this has a negative impact.  The AR/MA parameters are significant, but the ACF/PACF didn't warrant them and in essence mathematically they cancel each other out so no harm done....for this example.

The variance just with the causal is   .359252   and by adding 3 more parameters it becomes .3219 which is a non-significant reduction.

If there had been an outlier in the last period then this will have a big impact in the forecast.  There are outliers in this example and if the forecast was right after one of these it would have consequences.

SPSS's [Temporal Causal Model](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLVMB_23.0.0/spss/tutorials/timeseriesmodeling_gateway.html) discusses this capability as well.

[image: Actual and Cleansed of Outliers]

Here is the model from Autobox(a software I am affiliated with) with a denominator lag and numerator operators on the variable income and 16 outlier variables.

[image: Model]